# Range based for loop incorrectly outputs element of array with cout

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code correctly outputs the elements of an array for the first two for statements, but in the third it incorrectly outputs the elements of the array from a range based for loop when using cout (works with printf in the first).  Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{

int myArray[]={10,20,30,40,50};

for (int i : myArray) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}


for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << myArray[i] << endl;
}

for (int i : myArray) {
    cout << myArray[i] << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
10
20
30
40
50
10
20
30
40
50
-1707465271
0
1606417258
1606417820
1606418039
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have out of bound access in

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    cout << myArray[i] << endl;
}
```

as `i` would be 10,20,30,40,50.

you want

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

as you do with `printf`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, i is not acting as an iterator , but rather the value of each element...

Answer (score 1):

Change it the following way

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

It is the same loop as you wrote before it with using printf

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Take into account that you should include header `<cstdio>`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use index variable while using range based for loop, instead you need a local variable to retrieve the data from container or array that you need to loop

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    cout << myArray[i] << endl;
}
```

The above snippet of code should correct as follows:

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```